# how to test getter in salesforce lightning web components using jest?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

HI All i want write test case for getters in lwc component using jest can anyone help in this?

JS Code:

```
    get isDefaultVariant() {
if (this.variant.toLowerCase() === "default") {
  return true;
} else if (this.variant.toLowerCase() === "custom") {
  return false;
}
```

}

Html:

```
<template>
<!--flipcard starts-->
<div class={customFlipcardClass} >

    <div class="blocx-flipcard_inner">
        <!-- <template for:each={flipcardData} for:item='flipcardItem'> -->

        <div class={frontClass}>

            <template if:true={isDefaultVariant}>
                <div class="blocx-card blocx-card-post">
                    <div class="blocx-card_body">
                        <div class="profile-pic-section">
                            <img class="user-icon-img" src={MainImage} alt="user icon">
                        </div>
                        <div class="blocx-card_footer">
                            <p class="footer-text">{MainHeading}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </template>

            <template if:false={isDefaultVariant}>
                        <slot name="custom-main-content"></slot>
            </template>
        </div>
        <div class={backClass}>
            <template if:true={isDefaultVariant}>

                <div class="blocx-card blocx-card-post">
                    <div class="blocx-card_body">
                        <div class="blocx-card_header">
                            <div class="blocx-card_header-left">
                                <img src={MainImage} alt="user icon">
                                <span class="card_text-head">{FlipHeading}</span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- <div class="blocx-card_header-right"><span>1h ago</span></div> -->
                            <!-- <input type="text" value={flipCardValue} />
                            <button onclick={flipHandler}>Click</button> -->
                        </div>
                        <p class="blocx-card_text">{Flipcontent}</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </template>

            <template if:false={isDefaultVariant}>
                <slot name="custom-flip-content"></slot>
            </template>
        </div>
        <!-- </template> -->

    </div>

</div>
<!--flipcard ends-->
```

Comment: have you considered reading jest's documentation? I would encourage you to give it a shot and then update your post. Antoher quick pointer, considering this is just a generic programing question, i'd suggest you post this on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1):

> You need to actually test the markup which should reflect the property
>   set at getter

**flipcard.test.js:**

```
import { createElement } from "lwc";
import Flipcard from "c/flipcard";

describe("c-task-list tests", () => {
    test('default variant should have footer', () => {

        // Setup
        const element = createElement('c-flipcard', { is: Flipcard});
        element.MainHeading = "heading";
        element.variant = "default";

        document.body.appendChild(element);


        // Exercise
        return Promise.resolve().then(() => {

            // Verify
            //Note: in this case footer should be rendered
            const footer = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('.footer-text');
            expect(footer.textContent).toBe('heading');
        });
    });



    test('custom variant should not have footer', () => {

        // Setup
        const element = createElement('c-flipcard', { is: Flipcard});
        element.MainHeading = "heading";
        element.variant = "custom";

        document.body.appendChild(element);


        // Exercise
        return Promise.resolve().then(() => {

            // Verify
            //Note: in this case footer should not be rendered
            const footer = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('.footer-text');
            expect(footer).toBeNull();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: if the return value is boolean what should i do @Anmol Kumar

Comment: That depends on how you are using the getter method, please edit your question to add more context like the actual lwc code (HTML + js). if you are just learning I would recommend checking out online resources first, my recommendation: https://youtu.be/cAKYQpTC7MA

Comment: also, check https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes, for example, specific to LWC

Comment: thank you for the reply. i'll go through the link you shared and i have edited the code can u help me here@Anmol Kumar

Comment: Updated my answer @user80144